# Using the ABI or Microsoft.Graph How to achieve two-way synchronization with the ink of OneNote in your own application?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am designing a free software, positioning is to quickly record some temporary ideas, now through Microsoft.Graph You can upload the ink to OneNote. But now I want to pull ink from the notebook and keep the ink synchronization between this free software and the notebook. I try to log in to the same notebook account on multiple machines to realize the function of ink synchronization. How can I integrate ABI or API in other software to realize this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, its not exposed with Graph API yet. Being said that the closest one i see is that with [Office.js for OneNote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/onenote/onenote.inkword?view=onenote-js-1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get the entire page data with 
`?includeinkML=true&preAuthenticated=true&includeIDs=true`.
Then create a new page with the old data combined with the new ink data.
Finally delete the old page and update the page-id link from the old page to the new one.
Clunky, but I have found no other way until a "patch ink" option becomes available for the onenote-API

Comment: Because of the time-consuming problem of uploading and the time-consuming problem of syncing down in OneNote. This way is what I'm considering at present, but the experience is very poor. And you can't edit one page at the same time as the same time.

But if you open it on two machines, they can write on the same page. And it can be synchronized. I carefully observed the data returned by graph, and the two onenotes all returned the updated content based on one copy.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good, I am learning, these sentences are translated by translation software. It may be difficult to read.